# Power Query - Add Column if value exists on another table with HANA slow

Tags: sql, powerquery, hana

I'm pulling two tables in to Excel via HANA (the 'Source' below is the HANA SQL query) and am trying to add an additional column to Table 2 via Power Query based on whether or not a value exists in a column in Table 1.  The dataset is HUGE (probably just under 1,000,000 rows) and I've gotten it to work but it takes hours to add the column and it looks like it's searching tens of millions of rows of data with the column add.  I've moved things around, tried buffering and I've triggered errors and when I've gotten it to work, it's taking hours to refresh.

Need help understanding what's going on, what would make it faster and if there's a different/faster way to achieve the same result.

```
= Table2.AddColumn(Source, "Purchased", each if(List.Contains(List.Buffer(Table1[CUSTOMER_ID]),[CUSTOMER_NUMBER])=true) then "YES" else "NO")
```

Please advise

Comment: Try buffering in a previous step.  It it will still take hours. Better bet might be merging the tables

Comment: The only step before this one is the 'Source' step which is the query.  It wound up taking ~ 3 hours but that will work vs. the previous way I was pulling.  Thank you for jumping in.